# Creating package for class and checking format for string in c++

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ through online resource. I am just a beginner. I am trying to solve a question that I found online.

Create a class named Employee.

In the class, you are to have the following data members:

- `name`: String
- `id`: String
- `hours`: int
- `rate`: double
- private members

You are to create no-arg and parameterized constructors and the appropriate setters(accessors) and getters (mutators)

The class definition should also handle the following exceptions:

- An employee name should not be empty, otherwise an exception should be thrown.
- An employee `id` should have the form `LLNNNN`.  If that form is not received, an exception should be thrown.
- An employee's hours should neither be negative nor greater than `84`.  An exception should be thrown otherwise.
- An employee's pay rate should neither be negative nor greater than `25.00`. An exception should be thrown otherwise.

Demonstrate this class in a program (separate class or in the same class).

The exception messages should be appropriate to the specific exception that has occurred.

Create a package `employee` for the project.

And here is my program, which works,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee {
    public:
        string getName(void);
        string getId(void);
        int getHours(void);
        double getRate(void);

        void setName(string _name);
        void setId(string _id);
        void setHours(int _hours);
        void setRate(double _rate);

        Employee();
        Employee(string _name, string _id, int _hours, double _rate);

    private:
        string name;
        string id;
        int hours;
        double rate;

};

string Employee::getName() {
    return name;
}
string Employee::getId() {
    return id;
}
int Employee::getHours() {
    return hours;
}
double Employee::getRate() {
    return rate;
}
void Employee::setName(string _name) {
    if(_name.size() == 0) {
        throw "Name can not be empty";
    }
    name = _name;
}
void Employee::setId(string _id) {
    id = _id;
}
void Employee::setHours(int _hours) {
    if(_hours < 0 && _hours > 84) {
        throw "Hours must be between 1 to 84";
    }
    hours = _hours;
}
void Employee::setRate(double _rate) {
    if(_rate < 0.0 && _rate > 25.00) {
        throw "Rate must be between 0.0 and 25.00";
    }
    rate = _rate;
}
Employee::Employee() {};

Employee::Employee(string _name, string _id, int _hours, double _rate) {
    try{
        setName(_name);
        cout <<  getName() << endl;
    }catch(const char* msg) {
        cout << msg << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    string a;
    Employee p;
    p.setName("Ram");
    a = p.getName();
    cout<< a << endl;

}
```

Here are few things that I didn't understand.

1. An employee `id` should have the form `LLNNNN`. If that form is not received, an exception should be thrown.
   ->What is `LLNNNN` format ? I am not aware of this.
2. You are to create no-arg and parameterized constructors and the appropriate setters(accessors) and getters (mutators).
   -> Is it what I have done and declared constructor. I am confused on this.
3. Create a package `employee` for the project.
   -> I do not know what this mean.

If anyone would guide me through this it would be so helpful .

Thank you

Comment: `LLNNN` == Letter, Letter, Number, Number, Number, Number (I.e. an employee could have the ID `JN0292`)

Comment: *Create a package employee for the project.* I'm with you on that. I have no idea what they mean either.

Comment: *Is it what I have done and declared constructor. I am confused on this.* No need to be confused. Looks to me like you got it right.